# Apache Beam DirectRunner with Cloud Pub/Sub

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, direct-runner

I am trying to pass data from Cloud Pub/Sub to Google Cloud Storage. When I use runner `DataflowRunner` , the pipeline gets published to Google Cloud Dataflow and works as expected. However, for some testing I'd like the pipeline to run locally (but still read from Cloud Pub/Sub and write Cloud Storage). When I use the runner DirectRunner, the process writes out `INFO:apache_beam.runners.direct.direct_runner:Running pipeline with DirectRunner.`, but does nothing when a new message is published to Pub/Sub.

I am executing the pipeline with this command:

```
python dev_radim_dataflow_gcs_direct.py ^
  --project=<GCP_PROJECT> ^
  --region="europe-west3" ^
  --input_subscription="projects/data-uat-280814/subscriptions/dev-radim-dataflow" ^
  --output_path=gs://dev_radim/dataflow_dest_local/ ^
  --runner=DirectRunner ^
  --window_size=1 ^
  --temp_location=gs://dev_radim/dataflow_temp_local/
```

The full dev_radim_dataflow_gcs_direct.py file is here: https://pastebin.com/W7VphH5A

Any ideas why the message doesn't make it from Pub/Sub to GCS?

Comment: I ran your code using the command you provided. The pubsub message I sent is in json format and message `INFO:apache_beam.runners.direct.direct_runner:Running pipeline with DirectRunner.`  is also shown but I checked gcs bucket the output is written there and is just continously streaming. Are you expecting a different result?

Comment: That's exactly what I expect. In the light of your findings I went through the whole process and found out the issue was that there was another Dataflow Job connected to the same subscription. Once I created a new one for the job w DirectRunner, everything works as expected. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comment by @RadRussian as an answer, since this could happen for other people as well:

There was another consumer reading from the same subscription, so no messages ever got to the pipeline running in the DirectRunner. In this case the consumer was a Dataflow job, but it could be anything.